# Validating a facebook posting

Tags: facebook

I am trying to figure out if I can give somebody a "sharer" link where they click on it and then make a post to facebook.  After they have posted, I wish to be able to verify that this post has not been tampered with or at the very least deleted, lets say 2 weeks from the time it was posted.  Is there a way to programaticaly check if the post still exists and get the content of that post?

I know I can do the first part with some javascript such as this:

```
(function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/etc...";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

However, is there a way for me to check that what this user has posted still exists after 2 weeks?

Comment: If the purpose of that “verification” is that you want to reward users for sharing, then please be aware that you are __not allowed__ to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would only be possible by authorizing a user with the `publish_actions` permission. After that, posting something with the FB.ui dialog will return the post ID in the callback function. Of course you could also use `/me/feed` to post something then.

But authorizing a user just for this is pointless, it is not allowed to "incentivize" sharing, as you can read in the [platform policy](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/). So you are not allowed to reward the user for sharing in any way. Users need to share something because they really want to.

Also, you would never get through [Login Review](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review) with this, so it´s actually impossible.